# Access denied when using svcutil

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I am trying to consume a WCF service I wrote, but I can't get the `svcutil.exe` to generate a proxy.

Every path I try brings up access denied... What do I need to set to get permission?

> Generating files...
>   Error: Cannot create output file: C:\ClientCode.cs
>   Access to the path 'C:\ClientCode.cs' is denied.

Comment: Windows 7?  If so try 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: You nailed it! Damn windows security... You can make that a reponse and i'll mark as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using Windows 7 try 'Run as Administrator'.

As a bonus, you can eliminate this annoyance by opening 'User Account Control Settings' and change the setting to 'Never Notify'.